# Алгоритм обратного распространения ошибки - возникает ошибка на выходе нейронной сети

Tags: нейронные-сети, matlab

Написал нейронную сеть, используя алгоритм обратного распространения ошибки.

В теории, в конце обучения сумма квадратов ошибки по нейронам выходного слоя должна стремиться к нулю. У меня же после любого количества эпох обучения она "стабилизируется" на определенном значении (3).

Обучение с учителем, вектор входных данных - закодированные цифры/буквы, размерность входа - 35 (7х5, 1 - черный цвет, 0 - белый, например, буква Ю закодирована как 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена - неверно считал поправку весов + была ошибка в вычислении производной.

Answer (score 4):

`В теории, в конце обучения сумма квадратов ошибки по нейронам выходного слоя должна стремиться к нулю` - откуда у вас такая информация ?

В конце обучения мы должны подобрать такие веса нейронов при которых функция ошибки/потери имеет минимальное значение (т.е. глобальный минимум) - для более менее больших реальных датасетов практически никогда вы не сможете подобрать такие веса, что функция ошибки будет равна нулю. А если и получится то это скорее плохо, т.к. это показатель переобученной модели.

Comment: У меня всего 4 примера обучающей выборки, но преподаватель говорит, что ошибка должна идти к нулю или иметь небольшое значение. У меня же получается, что она идет примерно из 4 в 3.

Comment: Ну тогда опубликуйте данные и код...

Comment: Добавил код программы.

Comment: @Aleks А это хоть что за язык то? Добавьте метку с этим языком

Comment: Matlab. Мало людей тут знают этот язык, поэтому я надеялся получить ответ на свой вопрос без кода.. )